# Find columns to select, for spark.read(), from another Dataset - Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `Dataset[Year]` that has the following schema:

```scala
case class Year(day: Int, month: Int, Year: Int)
```

Is there any way to make a collection of the current schema?

I have tried:

```scala
println("Print  -> "+ds.collect().toList)
```

But the result were:
`Print  -> List([01,01,2022], [31,01,2022])`

I expected something like:
`Print  -> List(Year(01,01,2022), Year(31,01,2022)`

I know that with a map I can adjust it, but I am trying to create a generic method that accepts any schema, and for this I cannot add a map doing the conversion.

That is my method:

```scala
class SchemeList[A]{

  def set[A](ds: Dataset[A]): List[A] = {
    ds.collect().toList
  }

}
```

Apparently the method return is getting the correct signature, but when running the engine, it gets an error:

```scala
val setYears = new SchemeList[Year]
val YearList: List[Year] = setYears.set(df)
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to schemas.Schemas$Year
```

Comment: Hi Danilo! Welcome :) What are you trying to achieve once you `List[Year]` ? It is worth noting that once the `Dataset` has been transformed into `List` you won't be able to full benefit from having a spark cluster.

Comment: I need this list to use as variables when creating another dataframe via jdbc (I need to make a specific select within postgresql). Is there a more performative way to pass values from a dataframe as parameters in a select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your additional information in your comment:

> I need this list to use as variables when creating another dataframe via jdbc (I need to make a specific select within postgresql). Is there a more performative way to pass values from a dataframe as parameters in a select?

Given your initial dataset:

```scala
val yearsDS: Dataset[Year] = ???
```

and that you want to do something like:

```scala
val desiredColumns: Array[String] = ???

spark.read.jdbc(..).select(desiredColumns.head, desiredColumns.tail: _*)
```

You could find the column names of `yearsDS` by doing:

```scala
val desiredColumns: Array[String] = yearsDS.columns
```

---

Spark achieves this by using `def schema`, which is defined on `Dataset`.
You can see the [definition of def columns here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L586).

Answer (score -2):

May be you got a DataFrame,not a DataSet.
try to use "as" to transform dataframe to dataset.
like this

```
val year = Year(1,1,1)
val years = Array(year,year).toList
import spark.implicits._
val df = spark.
  sparkContext
  .parallelize(years)
  .toDF("day","month","Year")
  .as[Year]
println(df.collect().toList)
```

Comment: Danilo stated "I have a `Dataset[Year]`" so code to convert a `DataFrame` to `Dataset` isn't of much help.